# A synonym for the word "fanner"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

In the old days, kings and wealthy people used to hire fanners to make them feel cooler. Is there an English synonym for the word *fanner*?

Comment: [Punkah wallah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punkah_wallah)

Comment: It looks like an Indian expression. But,does it really exist in English?

Comment: sure, google punkah louver

Comment: @Mido Mido There are many words in English (particularly British English) that are Indian in origin. 'Char' for tea, 'Chit' for an official note, 'Bungalow' for a single storey house,  'Pukka' for something of which Jamie Oliver approves and so on.

Comment: Punkah wallah does exist in English, but I would consider it at least potentially offensive and certainly burdened with colonial history. I would not personally, as a Brit, use it outside of very limited historical context.

Answer (score 2):

***Fanbearer*** — [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fanbearer)

> *n.* One who carries a fan (especially those carrying fans for the pharaohs of Ancient Egypt)

[image: Fanbearer]